# C# httpwebrequest blank chars in responsestream

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, responsestream

I'm trying to read the reponse from a webserver using httpwebrequests in C#.
I use the following code:

```
UriBuilder urib = new UriBuilder();
urib.Host = "wikipedia.com";

HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(urib.Uri);
req.KeepAlive = false;
req.Host = "wikipedia.com/";
req.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
byte[] buffer = new byte[response.ContentLength];
System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
```

The code does indeed retrieve the correct amount of data (I compared the contentlength used to create the buffer, with the length of the console output, they're the same.
My problem is that the last 80% or so of the response is blank chars. They're all 0x00.
I tested this with several pages, including wikipedia.com and it just cuts off mid-file for some reason.

Have I misunderstood/misused the way to use webrequests or can anyone spot an error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this method:

```
public static String GetResponseString(Uri url, CookieContainer cc)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    request.CookieContainer = cc;
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    response.Close();

    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: That does indeed work. But for my education, what is it that makes the difference? The only real difference I see is the use of compression/decompression on the stream, and the prettier way of selecting the "GET" method.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. Your trying to read the entire response in one go using [Stream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) - that's not what it was designed for. This should be used for more optimal reading e.g. 4KB chunks.
2. Your reading a HTML response as ASCII encoding - are you sure the page doesn't contain any Unicode characters? I would stick to UTF-8 encoding to be on the safe side (or alternatively read the `Content-Type` header in the response).

When reading characters from a byte stream (which is what your `response` is essentially) the recommended approach is to use [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx). More specifically, if you want to read the entire stream in one go then use [StreamReader.ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx).

Your code could be shortened to:

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri("http://wikipedia.org"));
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```